# Printing address instead of value in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None


class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self,l1, l2):
        cur = l1
        num1 = ""
        num2 = ""
        finalNum = 0
        while cur != None:
            num1 = num1 + str(cur.val)
            cur = cur.next

        cur = l2
        while cur != None:
            num2 = num2 + str(cur.val)
            cur = cur.next

        num1 = num1[::-1]
        num2 = num2[::-1]

        finalNum = int(num1) + int(num2)
        finalNum = str(finalNum)[::-1]

        l3 = ListNode(int(finalNum[0]))
        cur = l3

        for i in finalNum[1:]:
            node = ListNode(int(i))
            cur.next = node
            cur = cur.next
        return l3


def main():
    numbers=Solution()
    l1=ListNode(234)
    l2=ListNode(465)
    obj=numbers.addTwoNumbers(l1,l2)
    print(str(obj))

main()
```

### Printing memory address instead of value in python 3

I'm trying to run the above code in my Pycharm and getting memory address printed instead of value.Can someone please guide me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you print an object of the class `ListNode`. as this class has no `__str__` method, it will print the default... suggestion: implement `__str__` for that class (e.g. `return str(self.val)` in there).

Answer (score 0):

Your function `addTwoNumbers()` returns `l3` which is an object, `ListNode`.

as your definition of `ListNode`:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

Your value `x`, is saved in `self.val`. So, you need to add `.val` to print the object's value :

```
...

def main():
    numbers=Solution()
    l1=ListNode(234)
    l2=ListNode(465)
    obj=numbers.addTwoNumbers(l1,l2)
    print(str(obj.val))

...
```

Comment: Hi @malioboro The output I'm trying to achieve is as below
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
I'm expecting the output to be 8-7 but I'm getting 6 as output

when we enter two integers 243 564 the numbers shoulders be reversed and resultant  number should be added

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `__str__()` method for your `ListNode` class so Python knows how to print this particular object. If it doesn't know, it just prints a generic object description:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response
Hi @malioboro The output I'm trying to achieve is as below Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4) Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8 Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807. I'm expecting the output to be 8-7 but I'm getting 6 as output when we enter two integers 243 564 the numbers shoulders be reversed and resultant number should be added.Hope you can help with solution